# Replace NA values with minimum observed value per group

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, data.table

Though there are some similar questions, I cannot find one answer that applies to my case in particular.

I just want to replace missing values (NA) in my `mydf` data frame with the minimum value observed per `COMPOUND` (or per `COMPOUND` and `SUBJECT`)

The following is a MWE with my best attempt (I have a long dataset, so something efficient like `data.table` would be best):

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(SUBJECT=rep(paste('subject',1:10,sep='_'), each=15),
                   TREATMENT=rep(c('A','B'), each=75),
                   TIME=rep(rep(paste('t',0:2,sep=''), each=5), 10),
                   COMPOUND=rep(paste('COMP',1:5,sep='-'), 30),
                   VALUE=rnorm(n=150, mean=20, sd=5))

#INTRODUCE RANDOM NAs
mydf$VALUE[which(mydf$VALUE %in% sample(mydf$VALUE, 15))] <- NA

#CHECK WHICH ARE THE MIN VALUES PER COMPOUND
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
#DT[, list(min.val=min(VALUE, na.rm=TRUE)), by=list(SUBJECT=SUBJECT, COMPOUND=COMPOUND)]
DT[, list(min.val=min(VALUE, na.rm=TRUE)), by=COMPOUND]

#REPLACE MISSING VALUES WITH MIN VALUES PER COMPOUND
#mydf <- as.data.frame(DT[, VALUE2 := min(VALUE[!is.na(VALUE)]), by=list(SUBJECT=SUBJECT, COMPOUND=COMPOUND)])
mydf <- as.data.frame(DT[, VALUE2 := min(VALUE[!is.na(VALUE)]), by=COMPOUND])
mydf
```

As you can see, in my attempt, all values are replaced by the min, but I want only NAs to be replaced.

I want this:

```
> head(mydf, 30)
     SUBJECT TREATMENT TIME COMPOUND     VALUE    VALUE2
1  subject_1         A   t0   COMP-1 16.867731 16.867731
2  subject_1         A   t0   COMP-2 20.918217 20.918217
3  subject_1         A   t0   COMP-3 15.821857 15.821857
4  subject_1         A   t0   COMP-4 27.976404 27.976404
5  subject_1         A   t0   COMP-5 21.647539 21.647539
6  subject_1         A   t1   COMP-1 15.897658 15.897658
7  subject_1         A   t1   COMP-2 22.437145 22.437145
8  subject_1         A   t1   COMP-3 23.691624 23.691624
9  subject_1         A   t1   COMP-4 22.878907 22.878907
10 subject_1         A   t1   COMP-5        NA 11.796972
11 subject_1         A   t2   COMP-1 27.558906 27.558906
12 subject_1         A   t2   COMP-2 21.949216 21.949216
13 subject_1         A   t2   COMP-3 16.893797 16.893797
14 subject_1         A   t2   COMP-4  8.926501  8.926501
15 subject_1         A   t2   COMP-5        NA 11.796972
16 subject_2         A   t0   COMP-1 19.775332 19.775332
17 subject_2         A   t0   COMP-2 19.919049 19.919049
18 subject_2         A   t0   COMP-3 24.719181 24.719181
19 subject_2         A   t0   COMP-4 24.106106 24.106106
20 subject_2         A   t0   COMP-5        NA 11.796972
21 subject_2         A   t1   COMP-1 24.594887 24.594887
22 subject_2         A   t1   COMP-2 23.910682 23.910682
23 subject_2         A   t1   COMP-3 20.372825 20.372825
24 subject_2         A   t1   COMP-4 10.053242 10.053242
25 subject_2         A   t1   COMP-5 23.099129 23.099129
26 subject_2         A   t2   COMP-1        NA 10.428203
27 subject_2         A   t2   COMP-2        NA 10.975207
28 subject_2         A   t2   COMP-3 12.646238 12.646238
29 subject_2         A   t2   COMP-4 17.609250 17.609250
30 subject_2         A   t2   COMP-5 22.089708 22.089708
```

Comment: `mydf %>%
  group_by(COMPOUND) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = ifelse(is.na(VALUE), min(VALUE, na.rm = T), VALUE))
`

Comment: In the marked duplicate, replace `mean` with `min` and you have the answer.

Comment: Alright! Thanks! I have no idea of `dplyr` though... how would you group_by COMPOUND and SUBJECT?

Comment: same way.. `mydf %>% group_by(COMPOUND, SUBJECT) %>% mutate(Value2 = ifelse(is.na(VALUE), min(VALUE, na.rm = T), VALUE))`

Comment: oh alright! I was trying c() and list()... Thanks!